# In Mongodb, what are the differences of working process between Primary key(IDHACK) and Secondary key(IXSCAN)?

Tags: mongodb

I have made some tests to compare the find() performance between Primary key and Secondary key.

I inserted 1million dummy data in a collection and an object looks like bellow.

```
{ "_id" : "1/1/1",
  "1stDocumentNum : "1/1/1"
}
```

After Inserting all dummy data, "_id" field already had an index(Primary key) that Mongodb automatically assigns on _id field and I created additional Index on "1stDocumentNum" filed(Secondary Key).

When I have tested finding an object in two different ways,

> 1. finding an object with "_id" field
> 2. finding an object with "1stDocumentNum" field

the results were like below.

Using Jmeter, Nginx, Php

1. finding an object with "_id" field
   Throughput per second: 10622

In explain(),

```
"winningPlan" : {
"stage" : "IDHACK"
},
```

2. finding an object with "1stDocumentNum" field
   Throughput per second: 8751

In explain(),

```
"winningPlan" : {
"stage" : "FETCH",
"inputStage" : {
"stage" : "IXSCAN",
"keyPattern" : {
"1stDocumentNum" : 1
},
```

I want to know what are the differencs between IDHACK and IXSCAN and how they work differently.

If they work as exactly the same, the reason why the throughputs are different is from the number of stages in explain()?

Anybody can help me understand it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include results of the second query with `explain(true)` (all candidate plans) and your specific version of MongoDB server (x.y.z). Was your test only using reads or were concurrent writes happening on the same collection? The `IDHACK` stage means that a query used the `_id` index and bypassed the usual [query planner](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/). There may be extra overhead on the secondary query if there are multiple candidate plans or frequent plan re-evaluation, but outside of query planning both indexes should have similar execution.

Comment: The full `explain(true)` output (aka [`allPlansExecution` verbosity](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#behavior)) will provide more insight on whether different query paths are doing more work. [Explain results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) may vary somewhat depending on your version of MongoDB server.

Comment: Thank you, Steenie! You gave me many points I can check more.
I really appreciate your comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDHACK means that your query has chosen to use _id field index.
IXSCAN means your that query is using a regular index.

It is just about query path optimization.

"_id" is by default a field with hashed index and hashed index works slow for small data sets (the hashing overhead).
"1stDocumentNum" : 1 is a binary tree index and it works faster for small data sets.

That's why in your example 1stDocumentNum index is faster then _id.

Try to run the same tests with 10 billion documents and you will see that hashed index works faster (usually,.. depends on hash algorithm distribution).

Comment: `IDHACK` means that a query used the `_id` index and bypassed the query planning stage. The "hack" is referring to bypassing query planning since `_id` is both required and unique. An `_id` index is not hashed by default (and hashed index values in MongoDB are still stored as B-tree). There isn't enough information to understand the comparison results in the question, but it is definitely unrelated to hashed indexes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Although I need to check more with your point of view, I accepted your answer anyway!